# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, eigenvalue, observables, quantum-measurements

I can calculate them mathematically but I don't understand the physical meaning of these concepts. My knowledge  is purely algorithmic and lacks actual insight, how do I picture eigenvalues/eigenvectors in my mind.

Comment: we normally expect people to show a bit more evidence of finding things out using widely-available resources, and then asking a more specific question.

Comment: Do you understand their meaning in classical mechanics for linear systems? What books did you use to learn quantum mechanics from? Did you consult an actual physics textbook that uses quantum mechanics, like an introductory atomic and molecular physics textbook? It is very hard to get an intuition for quantum mechanics without understanding the actual phenomenology of quantum systems.

Comment: Really this is best done by properly reading a book on basic quantum theory.  I suspect you've read the math and largely ignored the text.  This is a common enough mistake by many students who are attracted to the math of quantum theory but not the rational and experimental results behind it.  I note your username in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to understand eigenvalues and eigenvectors in the context of matrices. Any n by n matrix can transform n-D space in some form. To make it easy to understand let's work with a 2by2 matrix
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
This $A$ can transform the entire 2D space. Let's check it for one vector in 2d space:
\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\
1  
\end{bmatrix} $\quad$This is nothing but $\hat{j}$ (read the column vector as $0\hat{i}+1\hat{j}$).

When $A$ acts on 2D cartesian space, every vector in the space including $\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\ 
  1
\end{bmatrix}$ transforms as:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\ 
  0 &1
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\ 
  1
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
  1  \\ 
  1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
So $A$ transforms $\hat{j}$ into $\hat{i}+\hat{j}$ ($=\hat{j'}$ for the transformed space). You can also check that it transforms $\hat{i}$ to $\hat{i}$ itself.
Check for any general vector and you'll see that $A$ shears the entire x-y plane. The coordinate axes in the transformed space are at $45^\circ$.

Now, $A$ is analogous to an *operator* in quantum mechanics and the column vectors are analogous to the *wavefunction* (usually called state vector in matrix language of Quantum Mechanics).

If $A$ acting on any vector gives the same vector but scaled by some factor, then this particular vector is called the **eigenvector** of $A$ (analogous to eigenfunction of operator $A$):
\begin{equation}
A\begin{bmatrix}
   a  \\ 
  b
\end{bmatrix}
=\lambda \begin{bmatrix}
   a  \\ 
  b
\end{bmatrix} \quad ...(*)\end{equation}

. In other words, If a vector in the original space retains it's direction in the transformed space then it is an eigenvector. In case of $A$ you can now tell that $\hat{i}$ is an eigenvector, so is any scaled version of $\hat{i}$, e.g,  $\begin{bmatrix}
   5  \\ 
  0
\end{bmatrix}$$=5$$\begin{bmatrix}
   1  \\ 
  0
\end{bmatrix}$ $=5\hat{i}$ , which is $\hat{i}$ scaled by 5, is also an eigenvector.

The scalar that scales the length of eigenvector in the transformed space is known as the **eigenvalue**($\lambda$, see $(*)$) corresponding to that particular eigenvector. e.g, in case of $\hat{i}$, $A\hat{i}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
0  
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
0  
\end{bmatrix}=1.\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\
0  
\end{bmatrix} $, compare this to $(*)$ and you'll see that the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $\hat{i}$ is $1$.

To give an example in Quantum Mechanics(in Heisenberg's matrix mechanics form): If you operate the Hamiltonian matrix($H$, a 3by3 matrix) on an eigenvector of $H$ ($\psi$, a 3by1 column vector), then $H\psi=E\psi$, where $E$ (=Energy) is the eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian operator corresponding to the eigenvector $\psi$.

Answer (score 2):

What is the physical meaning of the length of a vector? The answer I give to that question is that it's that aspect of the vector which doesn't change when you rotate your axes. What remains of the vector when you factor out its length is a unit vector, what we colloquially call "direction" when we describe a vector as having direction and magnitude.

Now, for an operator you also have elements of it that are invariant under rotations (or unitary operators - for the purpose of this explanation they're the same thing). The invariant elements are the operator's eigenvalues. What do you have left when you factor out an operator's eigenvalues? You have a rotation matrix that describes the orientation of the operator. We frequently describe the rows/columns of that orientation matrix as the eigenvectors of the matrix.

So, what makes eigenvectors special is that all observers agree on the eigenvalues of the operator, no matter what basis they're working in. The components of the eigenvectors, on the other hand, are maximally dependent on which basis you work in, and are thus, in a sense, subjective. You can derive objective information from eigenvectors, though. Just like the angles between vectors are rotation invariant, the matrices that translate one basis into another are also rotation invariant. Put more concretely, the inner product $\langle p | x\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-ipx/\hbar}$ is basis independent, even if the representations of $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ in other bases aren't.

You can actually go more general than rotations, of course. Eigenvalues are invariant under similarity transform for operators, but the analogy to vectors is easier to picture if we restrict our attention to rotations.

Comment: Love the analogy between eigenvalues and the magnitude of a vector, somehow I must have missed that in linear algebra. I think this is a very valuable answer. However, one might say that it focuses more on the mathematical meaning of eigenvalues and eigenvectors rather than their "physical" meaning. For instance, it might be appropriate to explain how, for a given physical observable property and its associated operator, the eigenvalues are the possible values of the property and the eigenvectors are the possible states of the system. Or something like that, my QM is rusty.

Comment: I disagree that it's focused on the mathematical properties of the operator. It comes from a relativistic perspective that for a quantity to be physically meaningful it has to be invariant under choice of coordinate system. You wouldn't have heard this in linear algebra, since defining tensors by how they transform is a physicist's perspective. As far as I know, I'm the first to apply it to this situation, arising from concerns about the gauge invariant parts of the field strength tensor in qcd.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximally dependent"?

Comment: @hft I mean determined entirely by. In the eigenbasis the representation of the eigenvectors in matrix form is diagonal. In other bases it takes on the form of an orthogonal (unitary) matrix, possibly multiplied by a diagonal matrix if the eigenvectors are unnormalized.

Comment: So the "maximally" doesn't really do any work here? I mean, they components don't change "the most" in any sense. Or do they?

Comment: @hft As in there is no part of them that is invariant under a change of coordinate systems. Or their form is determined entirely by the relationship between the eigenvectors and the basis they're being described in. Basically, "maximally" is meant to contrast "completely covariant" with "completely invariant."

Answer (score 1):

An eigenvector of an operator $\hat{O}$ is physically invariant (acquires a phase at most) when subjected to a transformation of which $\hat{O}$ is a generator. For example, momentum operator $\hat{p}$ is the generator for translation operation $\hat{T_a}=\exp(-i\hat{p}a/\hbar)$, and indeed an eigen-state of momentum $\psi(x)=\exp(-i p x)$ only acquires phase $\phi(a) = pa/\hbar$ upon translation, i.e. remains invariant. Another example is time evolution $\hat{U}=\exp(i\hat{H}t/\hbar)$. An eigenstate of the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ (i.e. the solution of the Schodinger equation) is invariant as time goes on that is,  remains "where it was". No transitions or any other physically significant dynamics occur.

Comment: You just told him to shut up and calculate. He probably knows those mathematical relationships. The question was "But what does it mean?". If you apply this to an excited state of a hydrogen atom (probably the most simple realistic quantum mechanics problem), then you get the wrong answer, anyway. This math basically tells you that the atom will simply sit there in an excited state and do nothing. That's false. In reality it will de-excite through an interaction with the em field and pretty fast, too, for most atomic transitions.

Comment: The excited states from the simple Kepler problem for the H atom decay only because the Hamiltonian used is incomplete. If you take a proper full Hamiltonian that includes the atom and the electromagnetic field and all other possible interactions (QED if you are only interested in the EM decay channels) and manage to find an exact solution/eigenstate (not necessarily the ground state), it will stay there indefinitely. Take Jaynes-Cummings model to illustrate.

Comment: Exactly. And if he reads an atomic physics textbook with both eyes open, then he will realize that the energy eigenvalues that jump out of the SE are not even what we are measuring. We are only measuring the energy differences between certain states. So the entire "measurement operator" aspect of von Neumann's mathematics is trivially unphysical, already. Most textbooks won't even explain to him that the SE models the reversible and the Born rule the irreversible dynamics of quantum mechanical systems.